# How to let the User Control fit in the grid of a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, grid

### i'm working on a project. And i have bump into some problems with WPF User Control.

I have added a User Control into the Window, and I want to put it at a specific grid. But User Control can not fit the gird, it is outside the Grid. It looks like this:
[User Control in Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e6qZ.png)

Here is the My User Control (TestGate)

```
<UserControl x:Class="MA.TestGate"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MA"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="auto" Width="auto">
<Grid >

    <Canvas Name="GateCanvas" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" >
        <Rectangle Name="Base" Fill="White" Height="300" Canvas.Left="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Canvas.Top="0" Width="300"/>
        <Polygon Name="Input_1" Points="0,25 86,75 0,125" Stroke="Black" Fill="White"></Polygon>
        <Polygon Name="Input_2" Points="0,175 86,225 0,275" Stroke="Black" Fill="White"></Polygon>
        <Polygon Name="Output" Points="275,125 275,175 300,175 300,125" Stroke="black" Fill="White"></Polygon>
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

[User Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aZAq.png)

---

And this is My Window

```
 <Window x:Class="MA.GATEWINDOW"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:myControls ="wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MA"        
    mc:Ignorable="d"        
    Title="GATEWINDOW" Height="720" Width="1280" Name="TheAndGate">

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1100"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="Gate" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:TestGate Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ></local:TestGate>
```

The window is like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1km9.png)

I will be so grateful if anyone can help me solve this problem! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `Width="auto"` or `Width="*"` to the first ColumnDefinition?

Comment: You could wrap the `UserControl` in a `ViewBox`. This would scale everything and stretch to the parent's bounds.

Comment: @RobinBennett ok, but i want to put the user control in the grid of Row = 0 Column = 0 while not changing the size of the grid, only to let the user control change its size.

Comment: `<ColumnDefinition Width="1100"></ColumnDefinition>` messes with that.  One of the other columns needs to be `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>`

Comment: @FelixCastor yes i have also tried this before, but after i added the User Control in the `ViewBox`, the User Control is gone.

Comment: Try changing `<ColumnDefinition Width="1100"></ColumnDefinition>` to `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>` without the viewbox

Comment: @FelixCastor Still not working, the User Control won't change. Only the grid changes itself.

Comment: @FelixCastor And now it looks like this : [link](https://imgur.com/bIIFw81)

Comment: If the outer grid can't resize to the control your best solution is still a ViewBox.  The canvas is getting its size from the polygons.

Comment: Just understood the problem, that your canvas doesn't fit in the Grid, in that case I agree with Felix, ViewBox is the best way to make fit it

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks to @FelixCastor, the Problem has solved. 
The User Control should be rewrite like this

```
            <Viewbox Height="auto" Width="auto">
            <Canvas Height="300" Width=" 300">
                <Rectangle Name="Base" Fill="White" Height="300" Canvas.Left="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Canvas.Top="0" Width="300"/>
                <Polygon Name="Input_1" Points="0,25 86,75 0,125" Stroke="Black" Fill="White"></Polygon>
                <Polygon Name="Input_2" Points="0,175 86,225 0,275" Stroke="Black" Fill="White"></Polygon>
                <Polygon Name="Output" Points="275,125 275,175 300,175 300,125" Stroke="black" Fill="White"></Polygon>
            </Canvas>
            </Viewbox>
```

And in the window we can also change a little bit like this:

```
        <Viewbox>
            <local:TestGate Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></local:TestGate>
        </Viewbox>
```

It looks like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkvt4.png)
And problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't fully understand your problem, I don't give a solution(and I see others already tried to help as possible in comments), but I would advise you to make the code "easier" for future. These are just advises, as I used to do the same "mistakes" when I started with WPF, but it becomes easier to read with little changes :

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

is totally useless (empty)

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Almost useless as you have only one column(but in fact, you can leave it if you think you may expand it in future).

```
<RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
```

Can be rewritten `<RowDefinition/>`

```
Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
```

Unnecessary information, if ="0" this can be just removed

your code would become :

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="Gate" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:TestGate Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ></local:TestGate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! I will pay attention to these in the future.